# Reading rows from an Oracle Object that is a table of other objects

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Forgive me, this is my first attempt at an Oracle Package, so I am hopefully missing something simple.

**EDIT** I sorted it...
Need to reference the actual declaring sub-type, as such:

```
 FOR j in outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_TENDERS.first..outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_TENDERS.last LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tender record : '
         || to_char(outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_TENDERS(j).TENDER_AMT)      || ' '
```

I created several a couple new Oracle Types, that will hold row data from my DB, as such:

```
create or replace 
TYPE ORDERS_TABLE 
IS TABLE OF ORDER_HEADER;
```

And that refers to my other type:

```
create or replace 
TYPE ORDER_HEADER FORCE
AS OBJECT (
  TRANSACTION_NUMBER    VARCHAR2(20),
  LOCATION_NUMBER       VARCHAR2(10),
  TERMINAL_NAME         VARCHAR2(25),       
  START_DATETIME        TIMESTAMP(6),
  GROSS_SALES_AMOUNT    NUMBER(20,0),
  NET_SALES_AMOUNT      NUMBER(20,0),
  SAVINGS_AMOUNT        NUMBER(20,0),
  SAVINGS_PRECISION     NUMBER(6,0),
  TOTAL_TAX             NUMBER(20,0),
  CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER   VARCHAR2(50),
  tbl_ORDER_LINES       ORDER_LINES,
  tbl_ORDER_TENDERS     ORDER_TENDERS,
  TBL_ORDER_REBATES     ORDER_REBATES
);
```

And for example, take the ORDER_TENDERS type:

```
create or replace 
TYPE ORDER_TENDERS  FORCE
AS TABLE OF ORDER_TENDER;
```

Which contains the rows of tender data:

```
create or replace 
TYPE ORDER_TENDER AS OBJECT 
( 
  TENDER_LINE_ID            NUMBER(20,0),
  TENDER_CODE               VARCHAR2(10),
  TENDER_AMT                NUMBER(20,0),
  UNENCODED_ACCOUNT_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(25)
);
```

So my package I think is working, where I can fill these objects (verified the HEADER stuff working at least.)  But I'm not sure how to test/debug/view the results when I call this package to see if I'm getting the ORDER_TENDER/ORDER_TENDERS data...

For example, this works fine:

```
declare
 invar varchar2(5);
 outvar ORDERS_TABLE;
 O_ORDER_TENDERS ORDER_TENDERS;
 O_ORDER_TENDER  ORDER_TENDER;
 begin
 sales_trickler.GetSales(invar, outvar);

 FOR i in 1..outvar.COUNT LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' record : ' 
      || to_char(outvar(i).TRANSACTION_NUMBER)      || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).LOCATION_NUMBER)         || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).TERMINAL_NAME)           || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER));

   END LOOP; 
end;
```

But how do I see the ORDER_TENDERS/ORDER_TENDER data?

I tried putting this extra FOR LOOP in, but it doesn't like how I'm referring to ORDER_TENDER(S)...

```
declare
 invar varchar2(5);
 outvar ORDERS_TABLE;
 O_ORDER_TENDERS ORDER_TENDERS;
 O_ORDER_TENDER  ORDER_TENDER;
 begin
 sales_trickler.GetSales(invar, outvar);

 FOR i in 1..outvar.COUNT LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' record : ' 
      || to_char(outvar(i).TRANSACTION_NUMBER)      || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).LOCATION_NUMBER)         || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).TERMINAL_NAME)           || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER));
      FOR j in 1..outvar(i).O_ORDER_TENDERS.COUNT LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tender record : '
      || to_char(O_ORDER_TENDERS(j).TENDER_AMT)      || ' '           
      );
      END LOOP;

   END LOOP; 
end;
```

I tried relating to outvar(i).ORDER_TENDERS but that didn't work either... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the calling code, I shouldn't refer to new instances of the sub-objects, I should refer to them 'as they live' in the original parameter being passed, as such:

```
 tbl_ORDER_LINES       ORDER_LINES,
 tbl_ORDER_TENDERS     ORDER_TENDERS,
 TBL_ORDER_REBATES     ORDER_REBATES
```

Here's the actual statement:

```
declare
 invar varchar2(5);
 outvar ORDERS_TABLE;
 begin
 sales_trickler.GetSales(invar, outvar);

 FOR i in 1..outvar.COUNT LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' record : ' 
      || to_char(outvar(i).TRANSACTION_NUMBER)      || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).LOCATION_NUMBER)         || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).TERMINAL_NAME)           || ' '
      || to_char(outvar(i).CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER));

       FOR j in outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_TENDERS.first..outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_TENDERS.last LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('tender record : '
         || to_char(outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_TENDERS(j).TENDER_AMT)      || ' ' 

  );
  END LOOP;
  --lines
   FOR j in outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_LINES.first..outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_LINES.last LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('line record : '
     || to_char(outvar(i).tbl_ORDER_LINES(j).SKU)      || ' ' 

  );
  END LOOP;
```

END LOOP; 
end;